# How to get custom markers in Google map through getx

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers, flutter-getx

I am newbie I just stuck in a problem I integrate Google map in my application the problem I have is I had added custom markers, but they are not showing when the application started instead, they are shown when I ctrl s(save) it from my side.

The code is of my controller:

```
List<Marker> marker = [];
```

```
 Future<Uint8List> getbytesfromassets(String path, int width) async {
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(path);
    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List(),
        targetHeight: width);
    ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
    return (await fi.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png))!
        .buffer
        .asUint8List();
  }

//  Getting custom marker
  getmarker() async {
    for (var i = 0; i < latlng_.length; i++) {
      final Uint8List icon = await getbytesfromassets(image.value, 70);
      marker.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(i.toString()),
        position: latlng_[i],
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(icon),
      ));
    }
  }
```

here is my View page code :

```
 Map map = Get.put(Map());
    return SafeArea(
      child: Obx(
        () => Scaffold(
          body: GoogleMap(
            myLocationEnabled: true,        
            markers: Set<Marker>.of(map.marker),
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            initialCameraPosition: map.kGooglePlex.value,
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              map.controllermap.complete(controller);
              
            },
          ),
```

I want to get my custom markers when my application started instead after saving.

Waiting for you guys help.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be a nice approach to solve this problem. Use GetX widget to build your map, this because it provides an initState where data can be loaded initially, then use builder. In this solution a use a CircularProgressIndicator and a variable inside a controller file to show something is still loading and when it is done, a map shows. Also declare your marker before and pass them to your getMarkers function.

View page

```
Uint8List? customMapMarker;
return GetX<MapController>(
  initState: (state) async {
    customMapMarker = await controller.getBytesFromAssets('./assets/custom_marker.png', 100);
    await controller.getUserLocation();
    );
  }, 
      builder: (_) {
    if (_.isLoading) {
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    } else {
      return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              GoogleMap(
                onMapCreated: (mapController) {
                  _.onMapCreated(mapController);
                },
                initialCameraPosition: map.kGooglePlex.value,
                markers: getMarker(customMapMarker!),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Markers function

```
getmarker(Uint8List icon) {
for (var i = 0; i < latlng_.length; i++) {
  marker.add(Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId(i.toString()),
    position: latlng_[i],
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(icon),
  ));
}
```

}